# How to split a string in javascript based on this specific scenario

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have simple concatenated string of Name, UserId & TaxId

```
"Tester-N-U Academic Development Center-[10703]-[27-2008258]"
```

How can ? break this into array of strings so that in `array[0]` is `'Tester-N-U Academic Development Center'`, in `array[1]` is `10703` and in `array[2]` is `27-2008258`

Here's what I tried

```
const input = $scope.Name_UserId_TaxID;
const output = input.match(/[^[\]]+(?=\])/g);
const splitProviderName = $scope.selectedValue.Name_UserId_TaxID.split('-', 1);
$scope.selectedProviderName = splitProviderName[0];
$scope.selectedProviderID = output[0];
$scope.selectedTaxID = output[1];
```

But the problem here is I am only getting the word Tester I am expecting Tester-N-U Academic Development Center

Comment: You could use a regular expression, but the best solution would be to change the string format to provide the values separately.

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: What delimiter do you want to use?

Comment: Given your update, are you using Angular?

Comment: Try `input.match(/(.*)-\[(.*)\]-\[(.*)\]/)`

Comment: `"Tester-N-U Academic Development Center-[10703]-[27-2008258]".replace(/]/g, '').split('-[')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this match based on lookahead regex:

```js
var str = 'Tester-N-U Academic Development Center-[10703]-[27-2008258]';

var arr = str.match(/(?<=\[)[\d-]+(?=\])|^.+?(?=-\[)/g);

console.log(arr);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FLUUJN/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\[)`: Assert that there is `[` at previous position
- `[\d-]+`: Match 1 or more of digit or hyphen characters
- `(?=\])`: Assert that there is `]` at next position
- `|`: OR
- `^.+?`: Match 1 or of any characters (non-greedy)
- `(?=-\[)`: Assert that there is `-[` at next position

Comment: for regex expression

Comment: You can click on `Run Code Snippet` to see a live demo. I suspect you're running an older Javascript regex engine that may not support lookbehind. Can you try: `/[\d-]+(?=\])|^.+?(?=-\[)/` as regex?

Comment: try to put array [1]  getting undefined

Comment: This works thank you what if the name is like this `'Tester-N-U Academic Development Center~[10703]~[27-2008258]';` used `~` as separator

Comment: but I want to exclude brackets also for userId & TaxId

Comment: 'Tester-N-U Academic Development Center~[10703]~[27-2008258]'

Comment: Array[0] has 'Tester-N-U Academic Development Center', Array[1] = 10703, Array [2] = 27-2008258

Comment: oh sorry use `/[\d-]+(?=\])|^.+?(?=~\[)/` for match.

Comment: I am getting undefined in array[1]

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```js
var s = "Tester-N-U Academic Development Center-[10703]-[27-2008258]";
var rx = /-\[([^\][]*)]/;
console.log(s.split(rx).filter(Boolean));
```

The regex matches

- `-\[` - `-[`
- `([^\][]*)` - captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

Since the `String#split` returns all captured substrings, too, the value in Group 1 lands in the resulting array.

Note you do not need to use `g` as `split` looks for all matches in the input by default.

Note that `.filter(Boolean)` is required to remove any empty items from the result.

If you know there are only 3 pieces of text you need to get from the string you may use

```
/^(.*)-\[([^\][]*)]-\[([^\][]*)]$/
```

and grab Group 1, Group 2 and Group 3 values out of it. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hsJX4X/1).

```js
var s = "Tester-N-U Academic Development Center-[10703]-[27-2008258]";
var rx = /^(.*)-\[([^\][]*)]-\[([^\][]*)]$/;
var result = s.match(rx);
if (result) {
   console.log("scope.selectedProviderName =", result[1]);
   console.log("scope.selectedProviderID =", result[2]);
   console.log("scope.selectedTaxID =", result[3]);
}
```

ES6+:

```js
var s = "Tester-N-U Academic Development Center-[10703]-[27-2008258]";
var rx = /^(.*)-\[([^\][]*)]-\[([^\][]*)]$/;
var [_,selectedProviderName,selectedProviderID,selectedTaxID] = s.match(rx);
console.log("scope.selectedProviderName =", selectedProviderName);
console.log("scope.selectedProviderID =", selectedProviderID);
console.log("scope.selectedTaxID =", selectedTaxID);
```

Comment: Where is the required jQuery? :-D